# Angular 8 dynamic loaded modules from different servers

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, es6-modules

Basing on architecture requirement I would like to create one Angular base project with sub-applications loaded from the different destinations as permission allows.

1. One project with main module **base** and modules **app1**, **app2** etc.
2. Load available URLs of sub-applications (location of bundles with module **app1**, **app2**)

   { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: someProviderFactory, deps: [SomeProvider], multi: true }
3. Load modules in the application before Angular run by NgModuleFactoryLoader.load (with useClass SystemJsNgModuleLoader) with routes, entryComponents ect.
4. Angular will be fired and will be created separate bundles for specific modules.
5. Finally in production version configuration will return bundle URL from different server of these modules (app1, app2) and will load base application as point 1-4.

I don't know how to build a production package and move modules bundles to different servers. For local configuration I use url:
*src/app/app1/app1.module#AnalysisModule*

But I don't know how split modules to a different servers. Any idea how to make it as point 1-5?